# Create C# Application with sqlite database in visual studio 2008 which will work in all other systems without any requiremnets

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, visual-studio-2008

I want to create a C# application with sqlite database in visual studio 2008. I have already created an application but it work only in my system. When I run it in other systems it stops working.

I am using visual studio 2008 and the Microsoft .net framework installed on my windows 32 bit is Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.3. 
However, in visual studio I can't select .NET Framework 4.5.3 and I selected .NET Framework 3.5.

I downloaded `Setup for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 3.5 SP1)` from  [http://system.data.sqlite.org/](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). I select `System.Data.SQLite.dll` file in my project refrences and put it my debug folder. Also I put `SQLite.Interop.dll` into folder... 
It does not work in 64bit windows.
Please tell me how can I have an application which I will be able to give a folder to anybody and I will be able to be sure that he can run app in any windows OS.

Comment: Did you inlcude VC++ redist with your package and installing on target computer?

Comment: You need to define "stops working." You also need to explain better what exactly you're doing to run the program on other systems, and how you're compiling the program (which configuration settings, etc). It's maybe worth noting that VS2008 only allows you to create apps with up to .NET 3.5; you need VS2010 to have inbuilt support for .NET 4. The code you're using could also be an issue. There are *lots* of possible factors here, and ideally you need to narrow down your question a lot before it's going to get a good answer on StackOverflow.